# Analyze recursion (lower bound)

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

Given the following code:

```
(1) e(n)
(2)    foo = 1
(3)    for j=0 to n-1
(4)        foo = foo + j + e(j)
(5)    return foo
```

I analyze the time complexity like this:

```
(2) c1 (constant time)
(3) sum j=0 to n-1 (c2 + T(j))
(5) c3 (constant time)

=> T(n) = c1 + sum j=0 to n-1 (c2+ T(j)) + c3 , n>=1
```

I want to show a exponentially lower bound, but without estimate except to say that c1=c2=c3=1 (because of the lower bound).

```
=> T(n) = 1 + sum j=0 to n-1 (1+T(j)) + 1, n>=1
```

My first question: I would take a look at the first n's, look for a pattern and would show the exponentially lower bound by induction. Is this way right? Is there a better way?

My second question: If I say the code lines (2) and (5) need only constant time, I can ignore them. Then I get

```
T(n) = sum j=0 to n-1 (1+T(j)), n>=1
```

But then I have a other lower bound. Is this approach wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you are interested only in an order of magnitude, not the exact value. Thus, T(n)=17+2n, T(n)=3n-5 and T(n)=n are all the same: T(n) = O(n).
In your case, T(n) = 1+Sum_{0<=j < n}(1+T(j))+1 = 2+n+Sum_{0<=j < n}(T(j)). 2 is already dominated by n and can be discarded (n may be important - we are not sure at this point).

Now, let's look at T(n+1) = 2 + (n+1) + Sum_{0<=j < n+1}(T(j)) = 2 + n + 1 + Sum_{0<=j < n}(T(j)) + T(n) = T(n)+T(n)+1 = 2*T(n)+1 = 2^(n+1)*T(0)+2^(n+1)-1. Considering T(0) = 2 = O(1), we get estimate T(n) = O(2^n).

Comment: Why is 2*T(n)+1 = 2^(n+1)*T(0)+2^(n+1)-1?

Comment: @Elternhaus Intuitively, you can get this by applying the same equality over and over: T(n+1) = 2^(1)*T(n)+2^(1)-1 = 2^(1)*(2^1*T(n-1)+2^1-1)+2^(1)-1 = 2^(2)*T(n-1)+2^(2)-2^(1)+2^(1)-1 = 2^(2)*T(n-1)+2^(2)-1 = ... = 2^(k)*T(n+1-k)+2^k-1 = 2^(n+1)*T(n+1-(n+1))+2^(n+1)-1 = 2^(n+1)*T(0)+2^(n+1)-1. For a strict method for different expressions this comment character limit is too small (and it's somewhat an art, not a simple algorithm for all recurrences). There is a good book, "Concrete Mathematics" (by Graham, Knuth, Patashnik).

Comment: But you have to show  T(n+1) = 2*T(n)+1 = 2^(n+1)*T(0)+2^(n+1)-1 by induction, right?

Comment: @Elternhaus Here is the trick: you can **prove** that (T(n+1)=2*T(n)+1) implies R(n)~(T(n) = 2^n*T(0)+2^n-1) by different ways, it is really simple. Induction is one way: R(0) is trivial (T(0) = 2^0*T(0)+2^0-1), R(k) gives T(k+1)=2*T(k)+1=(by R(k))=2^(k+1)*T(0)+2^(k+1)-1, thus proving R(k)=>R(k+1) and thus, by induction principle, R(n) holds for all natural n. **Real** problem here is to figure out _what_ to prove. To get so-called "closed" form of T(n) by its recurrence form. And, as I said, it's somewhat an art; I tried to explain how did I get the expression in this particular case.